# develop web app depending on existing android app which has sqlite database

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have developed **android app** in ionic 3 with sqlite offline database which sync to server when there is a network available. this is working perfectly now.

Now i want to move on and develop **PWA app** for same, but i think sqlite not works in browser platform. if works how to make it work. Now its giving **"error typeerror cannot read property 'executesql' of undefined in browser platform ionic 3"** after running app.

i have struck here please help me out how to move on now.

**Basically i want to develop web app depending on existing android app which has sqlite database**.

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, there’s no SQLite in the browser. It has Local Storage as a limited viable alternative.

Comment: my app has 40 sqlite tables, can i use localstorage to store that much of data

Answer (score 1):

For PWA offline storage usually the best choice is to go with `IndexedDB`. It is a database API built in the browser. It is not a SQL database so you would have to migrate your tables. [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa) you can find more information. Also `IndexedDB` is a little tricky to work with, you might wanna give a try to [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com). It is a database for browsers that uses `IndexedDB` under the hood and is easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but can i move from sqlite to indexedDB, is it easy to change. I think IndexDB is limited storage.